# What does %folder% do?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I once saw a path specified in VB.NET in the following way:

`%folder%/some/random/path`

My question is what does `%folder%` actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Folder Environment Variables in Windows:**

Here are a few of the folders defined as automatically populated environment variables in Windows:

- `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` - All User's Profile
- `%HOMEDRIVE%` -  Home drive (often C:)
- `%USERPROFILE%` - Current User's Profile
- `%TEMP%` - Temporary file Folder
- `%SYSTEMROOT%` - Windows folder
- `%APPDATA%` - Profile's application data folder
- `%PROGRAMFILES%` - Default Program Install Folder

Try these in a command window (start > run > cmd)

At the command prompt, try:

```
cd %PROGRAMFILES%
```

**Other Interesting Built-In Dynamic Environment Variables:**

Here are some other truly built-in environment settings that are not folders:

- `%DATE%` - Current Date
- `%TIME%` - Current Time
- `%RANDOM%` - Random number between 0 and 32767

At the command prompt, try:

```
echo %RANDOM%
```

To list these built-in variables and how they behave, try this at the prompt:

```
set /?
```

Comment: Thank you. So a directory name enclosed on % means that it is a folder that is controlled by windows?
But does %folder% specifically mean anything?

Comment: BTW - to answer your exact question: %folder% has nothing to do with VB.NET that I'm aware of.

Comment: the %'s are for environment variables.  Anything set in windows you can retrieve with %[variablename]%.  List all of your custom set variables at the command prompt by typing SET